# Regular expression for allow - not more then 2 times

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp

i am using `^(^[a-z]?[a0-z9]+[.|-][a0-z9]+[a-z]+[.|-][a0-z9]+[a-z]?$)+$` , this force user type 2 hyphen(-) in his expression ....

But i need that regular expression can allow maximum 2 hypen and minimum one hyphen in his expression....

Comment: What do you think `[a0-z9]` match? Your expression matches strings that have 2 `.` or `|` or `-`

Comment: This regex appears to contain many mistakes.  Please describe exactly what you want to match and provide some sample data that should match.  Then we can help you with a better regex.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? String1: abc-pqr, String2: aaa-bbb, String3: aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd, where String 1 and 2 are valid and 3 is invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple re implementation.

`/^[^-]+(-[^-]+){1,2}$/`

And the test result:

```
"123".match(/^[^-]+(-[^-]+){1,2}$/)
null

"123-123".match(/^[^-]+(-[^-]+){1,2}$/)
["123-123", "-123"]

"123-123-123".match(/^[^-]+(-[^-]+){1,2}$/)
["123-123-123", "-123"]

"123-123-123-123".match(/^[^-]+(-[^-]+){1,2}$/)
null
```

And if you just copy one from other, then you should try to write one by yourself.
If not, you should delete it and restart.

Comment: hmmmmm. Did I misunderstand the purpose?

Comment: maybe I did. The question is not clear. I was treating the question as literally any string with one or two hyphens in it, but maybe what he wants is more than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^-]*-+[^-]*-{0,1}[^-]*$
```

String1: abc-pqr, 
String2: aaa-bbb, 
String3 aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd,
where String 1 and 2 are valid and 3 is invalid?

This allows String 1 and 2. But not 3.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work...

```
/^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$/
```

It works by capturing anything except a hyphen (zero or more times), then a hyphen, then anything else again, then another hyphen, then anything else. It has a start and end marker to ensure that the whole string does not contain any more hyphens.

Breaks down like this...

```
/       # begin regex
^       # start of string
[^-]*   # not hyphen ([^-]), zero or more times (*)
-       # hyphen
[^-]*   # not hyphen ([^-]), zero or more times (*)
-       # hyphen
[^-]*   # not hyphen ([^-]), zero or more times (*)
$       # end of string
/       # end regex
```